# Why is the animation frame not working?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I was trying to test a simple animation frame and I so far have not been able to get it to work. I want to move a AAA tag across the screen to the right.

How can I animate it so that when the page loads that it moves slowly to the right across the screen? I am new to the requestAnimationFrame.

Sub Question: you would not have to use any requestAnimationFrame but couldn't you just rather use JavaScript code to move the object across the screen.

HTML Code:

```
 <html>
 <body>
  <!--  <script language="javascript" SRC="poker.js"></script>-->
  <div id="test">AAA</div>
  <script>
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                   window.oRequestAnimationFrame;


    var start = null;

    var d = document.getElementById("test");

    function step(timestamp) {
      var progress;

      if (start === null) {
        start = timestamp;
      }

      progress = timestamp - start;

      d.style.left = Math.min(progress/10, 200) + "px";

      if (progress < 2000) {
        requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(step);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you won't be able to move your `div` across unless it has `absolute` position style or similar.

Comment: Paul Irish has a great post about using `requestAnimationFrame` including a robust polyfill and examples on how to get started: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: can you add some CSS please?

Comment: Your code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/9w8ofzbj/1/) when adding positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not move `static` positioned elements with `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` properties. You have to give `#test` position `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` to get it working:

```
#test{
    position: relative;
}
```

`left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties only work for positioned elements. By default, an element has `position: static;`

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/t4ynnpbo/

**UPDATE**

As I explained in the comments, you could have used `transition` CSS property to achieve the same.

Your CSS would be:

```
#test2{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    left: 0;
}
```

And just 1 line of JS code:

```
document.getElementById("test2").setAttribute('style', 'left: 200px');
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/t4ynnpbo/1/

Comment: But you could do the same thing with out the animationFrame correct?

Comment: @user3376708 yes that is correct, you can use `transition` CSS property on the element you want to animate and simply change `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom` CSS property value by JS and it will animate too. Since I see you are using vainilla JS and not jQuery I didn't advice to use `.animate()` jQuery method but you can use that too.

Comment: @user3376708 see the update for the working sample using `transition` CSS property. You can do it also with `.animate()` jQuery method but since I see you are using vanilla JS I didn't include jQuery in my answer